# Issue about alpha vantage foreign exchange

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, forex, alpha-vantage

So I created a web scraper code using Python for Forex as a resume project. To achieve that functionality, I utilized the BeautifulSoup library and Alpha Vantage API. However, in my terminal, it keeps on saying the error - "alpha_vantage.foreignexchange" could not be resolved. I don't understand how it can't work considering that my codebase is built normally.

This is my codebase:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange

def get_forex_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        # Extract forex information from the webpage using BeautifulSoup
        # Modify the below code to extract specific data you need

        # Example:
        forex_info = soup.find('div', {'class': 'forex-info'})
        if forex_info:
            data = forex_info.get_text()
            return data
        else:
            print("Forex information not found on the webpage.")
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch data. Check the URL or your internet connection.")
    return None

def save_to_txt(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(data)

def get_realtime_exchange_rate(api_key, from_currency, to_currency):
    try:
        fx = ForeignExchange(key=api_key)
        data, _ = fx.get_currency_exchange_rate(from_currency=from_currency, to_currency=to_currency)
        return data['5. Exchange Rate']
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching real-time exchange rate: {e}")
        return None

def get_historical_exchange_rates(api_key, from_currency, to_currency, start_date, end_date):
    try:
        fx = ForeignExchange(key=api_key)
        data, _ = fx.get_currency_exchange_rate(from_currency=from_currency, to_currency=to_currency, date_format='YYYY-MM-DD', outputsize='full')
        rates = data['Time Series FX (Daily)']
        historical_rates = {}
        for date, rate_info in rates.items():
            if start_date <= date <= end_date:
                historical_rates[date] = rate_info['4. close']
        return historical_rates
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching historical exchange rates: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Functionality 1: Currency Pair Selection
    from_currency = input("Enter the base currency (e.g., USD): ").upper()
    to_currency = input("Enter the target currency (e.g., EUR): ").upper()

    # Functionality 2: Data Validation and Error Handling
    url = input("Enter the URL for forex information: ")

    forex_data = get_forex_data(url)
    if forex_data:
        save_to_txt('forex_info.txt', forex_data)
        print("Forex information saved to 'forex_info.txt'.")

    # Functionality 3: Real-Time Exchange Rate
    alpha_vantage_api_key = # Replace 'YOUR_ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY'
    if alpha_vantage_api_key:
        exchange_rate = get_realtime_exchange_rate(alpha_vantage_api_key, from_currency, to_currency)
        if exchange_rate:
            print(f"Real-Time Exchange Rate ({from_currency}/{to_currency}): {exchange_rate}")
    else:
        print("Please provide a valid Alpha Vantage API key to fetch real-time exchange rate.")

    # Functionality 4: Historical Exchange Rates
    start_date = input("Enter the start date (YYYY-MM-DD) for historical exchange rates: ")
    end_date = input("Enter the end date (YYYY-MM-DD) for historical exchange rates: ")

    historical_rates = get_historical_exchange_rates(alpha_vantage_api_key, from_currency, to_currency, start_date, end_date)
    if historical_rates:
        print("Historical Exchange Rates:")
        for date, rate in historical_rates.items():
            print(f"{date}: {rate}")
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch historical exchange rates.")
```

But I think that I somehow can't access alpha vantage's capabilities.

Comment: Please describe your problem better. Is it that your code works in your IDE and not when executed from a terminal ? If so, it might be that you are not using the same Python environment in both cases, and `alpha_vantage` is not installed in the environment your terminal is using.

Comment: Can I send a link for the image of my terminal for better understanding? Also, thank you for replying, I though no one would help me.

Comment: https://ibb.co/92wBfLZ this is the picture of my terminal